# Drive NPN from Voltage Regulator?

Tags: bjt, npn, pulse, camera, open-collector

I am trying to get two disparate camera systems to talk to one another, specifically an Arri camera with a Preston system, and specifically to transmit a tally signal when the camera is recording.

System A (Arri) outputs a pulse signal from 5 V to 9 V at 24 Hz (once per frame) when recording, and System B (Preston) expects an open collector for the tally signal.

My plan was to use the 5/9 V pulse to drive a NPN transistor (I have some PN2222s here) into saturation, but I think I need to smooth the pulse into a steady signal for this to work. I know at least that 9 V is way too high for the PN2222 base.

I’m a little stuck here, however. Can I just use a linear regulator to get a steady voltage from the pulse signal, or is that needlessly complicated?

Comment: System B has an *input* for a tally signal?

Comment: What do you mean by "pulse signal from 5V to 9V"?  Do you mean that the signal is a 4V square wave riding on 5V, or that it goes from 0V to some high voltage, and that high voltage is between 5V and 9V?  Do you have an oscilloscope that you can capture the output from, or is there a manual you can link to?  If there's a picture of the pulse train in the manual, *editing your question* to include that picture would be good.

Comment: I’ve reached out to the camera manufacturer for a more detailed spec, still awaiting a reply. I haven’t had the chance to put an oscillator to an actual camera yet, but I believe it’s a square wave of 4 V with a 5 V base. I’ll update the question when I have more exact specs.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no technical information on the cameras, I will take a SWAG: Place a resistor in the 5K range in series with the base of the transistor. The emitter is connected to ground and the grounds of the two cameras need to be connected.

If connecting grounds causes conflict substitute an opto coupler for the transistor. Then place a 1K resistor in series with the LED portion and connect its ground to the controllers ground. Connect the transistor emitter to the receiving ground and the collector to the input. There is no base connection, if on the optocoupler let it float. There are a lot of schematics on line that will show this. You can look for "open collector" or "optocoupler circuit".

Comment: This makes sense! Joining grounds is not a problem (they'll be joined elsewhere regardless), but I'm still concerned about the 9 V high end of the pulse signal - the absolute maximum Vbe for the PN2222 is 5 V.

Comment: Your answer would be more complete and far easier to 'parse' if you used the site's built-in schematic editor to draw what you're proposing rather than trying to describe it with words ...